# Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have an array of days, which I am mapping in my `View` but I am getting warning that `Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.`, I am not able to understand why I am getting this error. I am new to react native, and I am trying to understand what every warning means

my code:

```
<ScrollView
  horizontal={true}
  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
  contentContainerStyle={styles.horizontalView}>
  {weekArray.map((item, index) => (
    <TouchableOpacity index={index} onPress={() => setIndexSelect(index)}>
      <Text
        style={{
          fontFamily: "Raleway-Regular",
          fontSize: SizeConfig.blockHeight * 2.1,
          color: indexSelect === index ? COLORS.blackDark : COLORS.blackLight,
        }}>
        {index === weekArray.length - 1 ? ` ${item.day} ` : ` ${item.day} | `}
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  ))}
</ScrollView>;
```

Comment: Check [Understanding unique keys for array children in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329382/understanding-unique-keys-for-array-children-in-react-js) you will get some idea. Basically, you have to define unique key for each view/element in loop

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding unique keys for array children in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329382/understanding-unique-keys-for-array-children-in-react-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is similar to passing an id to objects to recognise them. Similarly here in react-native you need to provide a key which can be a number or anything but different for each component to recognise that and to keep that seperate from others.

In your example you can pass a key at ;

```
<TouchableOpacity key={index} onPress={() => setIndexSelect(index)}> // If index is different for each component.
```

Answer (score 6):

In react you should pass a unique prop to each component if you are mapping components from an array.

```
{weekArray.map((item, index) => (
<TouchableOpacity index={index} onPress={() => setIndexSelect(index)} key={index}>
  <Text
    style={{
      fontFamily: "Raleway-Regular",
      fontSize: SizeConfig.blockHeight * 2.1,
      color: indexSelect === index ? COLORS.blackDark : COLORS.blackLight,
    }}>
    {index === weekArray.length - 1 ? ` ${item.day} ` : ` ${item.day} | `}
  </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

))}

key should be unique for each component.

Answer (score 2):

That's not an error but a warning. Every time you map over an array in jsx you have to provide a unique key prop. React uses the key prop to create a relationship between the component and the DOM element. The library uses this relationship to determine whether or not the component should be re-rendered.

do something like this:

```
<TouchableOpacity key={index} onPress={() => setIndexSelect(index)}>
```